# Parsing xml with XMLStreamReader

Tags: java, xml, sax

I want to parse an XML file.
The outcome has to be a list with the info about symbol="YHOO".

The XML file comes from yahoo using YQL. An example: http://goo.gl/xB84eN

```
private XMLStreamReader makeXML(URL url) throws XMLStreamException, IOException {
    InputStream stream = url.openStream();
    XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader xmlr =  xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(stream);
```

Now I want to get some data out of the XML using SAX. 
But I can't figure out how to get the attributes and elements using XMLStreamReader and his events described on: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html

I tried:

```
private void readXML() throws XMLStreamException {
    while(XMLStream.hasNext()) {
          if(next == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT){
             System.out.println(XMLStream.getName());
```

But how do I get for example all the data of "YHOO" with all the correct numbers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem can solved by changing the Handler class of SAX. This is specific for a given XML file.

I found it from [this document](http://www.journaldev.com/1198/java-sax-parser-example-tutorial-to-parse-xml-to-list-of-objects) helped me to solve my problem.
It seems SAX is very specific so you have to change the Handler to your needs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, you should always put the main information into your actual answer. External websites can change and we want SO to be a useful resource, even in the future.

Comment: The problem can solved by changing the Handler class of SAX. This is specific for your XML file.
Can't really generalize the answer. 
But I didn't really thought of the fact a site could disappear (too optimistic about the internet I guess.)